# MongoError: Edge locations in degrees

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get point within a polygon and I am using below query for getting data

```
loc: {
$geoWithin: {
    $geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
            [
                [
                    -117.83736,
                    33.73838
                ],
                [
                    -117.83588,
                    33.73837
                ],
                [
                    -117.83369,
                    33.73839
                ]...
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

}

But I am getting an error like

> Edges 1 and 3 cross. Edge locations in degrees:

How can I solve this?

Comment: it means the "shape" you're inputing mongo is not a valid polygon, if you can show us your entire code we might be able to pinpoint why.

Comment: How Can I validate the polygon cordinates?

Answer (score 0):

As i stated in the comments your coordinates list is an invalid polygon.

You need to validate each edge with every other edge using a simple check as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/).

Comment: @BhavikaPatel which SQL product do you use? Note that MongoDB's geo parsing follows the GeoJSON standard very strictly, and if the parser says that the polygon is invalid, the likelier scenario is that the SQL product doesn't follow the standard closely.

Comment: @BhavikaPatel it appears that the 51th and the 55th edge you have crosses each other, where they are not supposed to in a polygon. This exact message was displayed by MongoDB 4.0.9. You might want to double check how you create this polygon.

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha, Is there any way to validate the geoJson of polygon?

Comment: @BhavikaPatel I haven't been able to find a tool that lets you do that easily. Unfortunately a lot of GeoJSON tools are of varying qualities, so one tool might say it's ok when it's not (like in your case here).

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha, I have created polygon from EncodedPoints, below is sample string of polygon EncodedPoints.

"onvlEnfumU^k@dEyG~To^`BkClB{CZg@|AeCfDqFrBeDjCgEvA{BdAcBR[Ta@`AaBhB{CJQl@kAP]tCyEFI`@q@Xa@FFLCjdAhcAeOdVINuIhNoJnOqEjHaCzDkKvP}GxKiBvCIN??????EE??UUw@u@mCmCqIqISQ}H}HgEgEWWcBcBaCaCk@k@{B{BcBcBk@k@MKuBwBm@k@iAiAgDeD~KzKkLiLk@k@IGs@u@CCIG????"